# jquery find anchor with href matching variable

Tags: jquery, undefined, attr

I'm trying to find an anchor tag with an href attribute that matches a variable, but I keep getting an undefined error, though I know the matching element (and href) are there... Here is what I've tried:

```
var current = $('.show-on-scroll nav > .index.active').find('a:first').attr('href');
  console.log(current);


 var target = $('#headerNav #mainNavigation div a[href*=current]');
  console.log(target).attr('href');
```

Sorry if I'm not formatting my question correctly, I'm kinda new here.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: the second console log should be: `console.log(target.attr('href'));` . Besides, I'd recommend you to open JavaScript console and try the selectors live to make sure you're getting them right. For example, type in the console `$('.show-on-scroll nav > .index.active').find('a:first')`and see if it returns the <A>

Comment: You might need to share some html with us. Maybe you're not accessing the element correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need concatenate the value of the variable like

```js
var current = $('.myA').attr('href');
console.log(current);


var target = $('a[href*=' + current + ']');
alert(target.attr('href'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="hello" class="myA">Test</a>
<a href="hello" class="myB">Test 1</a>
```